# How to pass conditional varible in using Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

```
private static final String Accept = "Accept & continue";

public void acceptWorkspaceCreation() {
        //Wait for Set up a Work Profile Screen for Android 9 Pixel

        waitUtilByText(180, Accept);
        assertTrue("Couldn't click on Accept & continue.",
                findElementByIdAndClick("com.android.managedprovisioning", "next_button"));
}

public boolean waitUtilByText(int seconds, String text){
        String textStr = "//*[@text='" + text + "//*[@id='";

        return !new WebDriverWait(this.driver, seconds).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
                    .xpath(textStr))).isEmpty();
}
```

For some cases **Accept** value comes in caps **'ACCEPT & CONTINUE'**, How to validate both the strings in selenium.

Comment: What is `waitUtilByText`? Is that a Selenium method, or one of your own?

Comment: one of my own method which does this operation ```WebDriverWait(this.driver, seconds).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
                    .xpath(textStr))).isEmpty();```

Comment: That's the relevant bit of the code that you should be showing. Please [edit] your question to add it.

Comment: I have updated according to your comment, hope now it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you are waiting for only checks for one thing:

```
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(textStr))
```

So, presumably (as I am not familiar with Selenium), you can use the [`ExpectedConditions.or`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#or(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition...)) method to check a number of conditions, and wait for just one to be true:

```
ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(textStr)),
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(textStr2)))
```

where `textStr2` is the alternative text you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using native Android `UiSelector`'s `textMatches` method where You'd write matcher for both upper and lower case texts. If you want to stick to the Xpath anyways - it also has a text matcher. But first of all, investigate why the text changes - that's not a good practice.